# NodeJS Wait till a function has completed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application where i have a `Client` class, that needs to be executed with different configurations for each user when i receive a message on discord(It's a chat application having its own API calls for checking for new messages etc). I have initialized the obj constructor whenever i receive a new message with new configurations for that user, but the problem is when i receive multiple messages at the same time, only the latest user's configurations are used for all the client objects created. Attaching sample code from the application:

Wait for message code:

```
const app = require("./Client")
const app2 = require("./MyObject")

bot.on('message', async (message) => {

    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase(), pg;
    let client = await new app2.MyObject();

    //set all such configurations
    config.a = "valuea";

    // initialize my 
    pg = await new app.Client(config, client);

    let result = await pg.Main(bot, message, params).then((result) => {
        // Do stuff with result here
    });
});
```

Client class:

```
class Client {

    constructor(config, client) {
        this.config = config;
        this.client = client;
    }

    async Main(bot, message, params) {
        let result = {};
        this.client.setProperty1("prop");
        await this.client.doSOmething();
        result = await this.doSOmethingMore(message);
        this.client.doCleanUp();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I had also tried initializing the obj constructor in the Client class, but even that fails for some reason.

Any suggestions how Can i correct my code?

Comment: await / async only work with Promises.  You're calling await on a constructor (which also doesn't return a Promise, nor can it afaik).  Further, you don't await something and also call `.then()`.  As it stands, it's really hard to tell what you're trying to do, as you don't even have a MyObject but you initialize one.  Hard to correct code under the circumstances.

Comment: `this.config = config;` ...  `config.a = "valuea";`  .... You can't reuse the same config object, you need to create a new one for each client.

Comment: Is `pg` deliberately a global variable?

Comment: Updated code @Paul and Berrgi.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `.then` and `await` at the same time.

```
bot.on('message', async (message) => {

    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    let client = await new MyObject();

    //set all such configurations
    config.a = "valuea";

    // initialize my 
    pg = new app.Client(config, client);

    let result = await pg.Main(bot, message, params);
    // Do stuff with result here
    console.log(result);
});
```

(You don't need to use `await` at constructor call because it is not an async method)

*note: `async-await` will work on higher version of node than 7.6*

If you want to use `.then`:

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    new MyObject().then(client => {
        //set all such configurations
        config.a = "valuea";

        // initialize my 
        pg = new app.Client(config, client);

        pg.Main(bot, message, params).then(result => {
            // Do stuff with result here
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to be certain, since you don't include the `MyObject` code, but generally [it's a bad practice to return a promise from a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise).

Further, if you don't do it right, then whatever that promise resolves to might not in fact be the Client that your calling code expects.